# What is 'AskTbPTV' in HTTP User Agent?

Tags: user-agent

Searched on Google but couldn't find anything useful.
Programming some statistics about User Agents and came across this one:

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; MRA 5.8 (build 4157); .NET CLR 2.0.50727; AskTbPTV/5.11.3.15590)
```

What does *'AskTbPTV'* in HTTP User Agent stand for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ask.com toolbar http://apnstatic.ask.com/static/toolbar/everest/download/index.html?source=sp wich modify user agent string.